# Web in a desktop application: Good web browser controls?

Tags: browser, controls, desktop-application

I've been utlising a "web browser control" in desktop based applications (in my case Windows Forms .NET) for a number of years.  I mostly use it to create a familiar flow-based user interface that also allows a seamless transition to the internet where required.

I'm really tired of the IE browser control because of the poor quality html it generates on output.  Also,  I guess that it is really just IE7 behind the scenes and so has many of that browser "issues".  Despite this, it is quite a powerful control and provides rich interaction with your desktop app.

So, what other alternatives to the IE browser control are there?  I looked at a Mosaic equivalent a year ago but was disappointed with the number of unimplemented features, maybe this has improved recently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm..Interestingly

1. [Mozilla](http://www.iol.ie/~locka/mozilla/control.htm) seems to provide ActiveX control
2. [K-Melon](http://kmeleon.sourceforge.net/) is another Gecko based browser control

Answer (score 0):

Popular layout engines:

1. Mozilla Gecko
2. KHTML
3. WebKit (based on KHTML)

Though I'm not sure how easy it is to embed those in a .Net app.